# Separar divs agrupado y ordenado por números y letras Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, array

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
var array = [
 { 
   id: 1,
   unit: '1A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 2,
   unit: '2A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 3,
   unit: '3A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 4,
   unit: '4A',
   division: 1
 },
   { 
   id: 5,
   unit: '5A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 6,
   unit: '6A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 7,
   unit: '1A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 8,
   unit: '1B',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 9,
   unit: '2A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 10,
   unit: '2B',
   division: 2
 },
   { 
   id: 11,
   unit: '3A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 12,
   unit: '3B',
   division: 2
 }
];
```

El cual al recorrerlo y pintar los divs hace lo siguiente:

```css
.unit{
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div>Division 1</div>
<div class="unit">1A</div>
<div class="unit">2A</div>
<div class="unit">3A</div>
<div class="unit">4A</div>
<div class="unit">5A</div>
<div class="unit">6A</div>
<div>Division 2</div>
<div class="unit">1A</div>
<div class="unit">1B</div>
<div class="unit">2A</div>
<div class="unit">2B</div>
<div class="unit">3A</div>
<div class="unit">3B</div>
```

Pero quiero que quede de la siguiente manera:

```css
.unit{
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>Division 1</div>
<div class="unit">1A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div class="unit">2A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div class="unit">3A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div class="unit">4A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div class="unit">5A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div class="unit">6A</div>
<div class="unit">&nbps;</div>
<div>Division 2</div>
<div class="unit">1A</div>
<div class="unit">1B</div>
<div class="unit">2A</div>
<div class="unit">2B</div>
<div class="unit">3A</div>
<div class="unit">3B</div>
```

Lo que quiero es organizar los divs que tengan la letra A a la izquierda y los B a la derecha. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
var division = [];
var divs     = '';

for(var i in array){
   division.push(array[i].division);
}

division = unique(division);

for(var k in division){
  for(var j in array){
     if(division[k] == array[j].division){
        if(array[j].unit % 2 == 0){
           divs += '<div class="unit">'+array[j].unit+'</div>';
        }else{
           divs += '<div class="unit">'+array[j].unit+'</div>';
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Espero mi pregunta sea coherente y me puedan ayudar a entender un poco mejor esta duda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los resultados siempre van a venir ordenados por `unit` ascendente y no vas a tener mas que `A` y `B`, entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, unit: '1A', division: 1}, {id: 2, unit: '2A', division: 1}, {id: 3, unit: '3A', division: 1}, {id: 4, unit: '4A', division: 1}, {id: 5, unit: '5A', division: 1}, {id: 6, unit: '6A', division: 1}, {id: 7, unit: '1A', division: 2}, {id: 8, unit: '1B', division: 2}, {id: 9, unit: '2A', division: 2}, {id: 10, unit: '2B', division: 2}, {id: 11, unit: '3A', division: 2}, {id: 12, unit: '3B', division: 2}];

var division = 0,
  curNum = 0,
  html = '';

array.forEach(function(data, idx) {
  let num = parseInt(data.unit),
    next = array[idx + 1];

  if (division != data.division) {
    html += '<div>Division ' + data.division + '</div>';
    division = data.division;
  }

  html += '<div class="unit">' + data.unit + '</div>';

  if (curNum != num && next && next.unit != (num + 'B')) {
    html += '<div class="unit">&nbsp;</div>';
  }
  curNum = num;
});

document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = html
```

```css
.unit {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var division = [];
var divs = '';
var array = [
 { 
   id: 1,
   unit: '1A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 2,
   unit: '2A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 3,
   unit: '3A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 4,
   unit: '4A',
   division: 1
 },
   { 
   id: 5,
   unit: '5A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 6,
   unit: '6A',
   division: 1
 },
  { 
   id: 7,
   unit: '1A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 8,
   unit: '1B',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 9,
   unit: '2A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 10,
   unit: '2B',
   division: 2
 },
   { 
   id: 11,
   unit: '3A',
   division: 2
 },
  { 
   id: 12,
   unit: '3B',
   division: 2
 }
];

var s = array.length/2;
for(var i =0; i < array.length/2 ; i++){
   divs += `<div class="unit">${array[i].unit}</div><div class="unit">${array[i+s].unit}</div>`;
 
}
document.write(divs);
```

```css
.unit{
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```